# Scala: serialize case class to JSON , alternate names

Tags: json, scala, serialization, gson

Any way to serialize a Scala case class to JSON and have the ability to provide custom serialized names ?

For example, In Java this can be done using the Gson library :

```
 public class SomeClassWithFields {
   @SerializedName("name") private final String someField;
   private final String someOtherField;

   public SomeClassWithFields(String a, String b) {
     this.someField = a;
     this.someOtherField = b;
   }
 }
```

I tried doing this in Scala :

> case class SomeClassWithFields(@SerializedName("name")
>   someField:String)

but it seems to have no effect .

Any thoughts ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do it with spray-json calling the [jsonFormat overloads](https://github.com/spray/spray-json#providing-jsonformats-for-case-classes).

Here's how it would work with your example:

```
import spray.json._

case class SomeClassWithFields( someField:String)

object SomeClassJsonProtocol extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
  implicit val someClassFormat = jsonFormat(SomeClassWithFields,"name")
}
```

Comment: This answer was perfectly fine for 2014. Four years later @Corindiano provided a better answer with language features that had been added, but I don't think this deserves any down votes in 2021 and beyond.

Answer (score 4):

Yes it can be done. Here's how:

```
case class SomeClassWithFields(@(SerializedName @scala.annotation.meta.field)("name") someField:String)
```

The syntax is strange (note that the outer '@' wraps the "SerializedName" and the scala field annotation) but it works fine. See more details at: https://issues.scala-lang.org/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/SI-8975

Comment: Yep, It's some strange but It works for me Thanks so much  @Corindiano Dixie

Answer (score 2):

Further improving Corindiano's answer by making it into a **custom annotation**, which can be (re)used elsewhere.

```
import scala.annotation.meta.field

case class SomeClassWithFields(@SerializedNameField(value = "name") someField:String) { ... }
object SomeClassWithFields {
    type SerializedNameField = com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName @field
}
```