# Why is @SerializedName not serializing fields when using Scala (works fine without annotation)

Tags: scala, gson

I have the following Code

```
case class BaseObject(
    ...
    dnsRecord: Array[DNSEntry],
    @SerializedName("dnsRecord") dnsEntries: Array[DNSEntry]
)
```

When I run serialization the dnsRecord works fine whereas the dnsEntries is null...

[image]

**Update**

@fluffy reminded me of [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24292330/scala-serialize-case-class-to-json-alternate-names) I saw a while back so I changed things to

```
case class BaseObject(
    ...
    dnsRecord: Array[DNSEntry],
    @(SerializedName@scala.annotation.meta.field)("dnsRecord") dnsEntries: Array[DNSEntry]
)
```

This threw an issue because it tried to use the `dnsRecord` field which was already used.

Comment: Any reason for using a **Java** library instead of a **Scala** library? - BTW, **Arrays** are discouraged in general, but since they are mutable they shouldn't be in a case class.

Comment: Scala because it runs on a Spark cluster and it would be too much of a pain to convert

Comment: Also they should be immutable after serialization. That may not be what is actually happening :-) but that is what I would expect.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I missed the Arrays part at first what should they be instead? Like I said it shouldn't be a mutable list.

Comment: Also can't use ArraySeq because currently stuck on 2.12

Comment: I recently faced many questions that focus on using Gson in Scala, and the most I can tell on it now is just: Gson does not work fine with Scala, one should find a better tool. Why: Scala does a lot of complex things behind the scenes Gson is not aware of while being a pure Java-dedicated tool. The same goes to Kotlin. See more at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63125448/gson-with-scala-causes-stackoverflow-for-enumerations and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62259410/how-to-deserialize-a-json-string-that-contains-with-scala

Comment: Now back to the very question. `@SerializedName` is designed to work with fields, not (case class constructor) parameters, as long as Gson `ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory` takes object fields in account, not its methods. In the second linked Q/A there's a deeper explanation. In short, `@(SerializedName@field)("dnsRecord") dnsEntries: Array[DNSEntry]` might work for you.

Comment: @fluffy Thanks will confirm and then have you create an answer

Comment: @fluffy for some reason I needed to include the namespace

Comment: @JGleason My suggestion was to use just `List` or `Vector` and use **circe** or **ujson** or **play-json** or any other Scala native library for parsing jsons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer looked like this...

```
case class BaseObject(
    ...
    @(SerializedName@scala.annotation.meta.field)("dnsRecord") dnsEntries: Array[DNSEntry]
)
```

or even better

```
object GsonScala {
  type SerializedName = com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName @scala.annotation.meta.field
}
case class BaseObject(
    ...
    @GsonScala.SerializedName("dnsRecord") dnsEntries: Array[DNSEntry]
)
```